# control of two var JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, arrays

I do not have a DB

how can I compare the values ​​taken from the keyboard with those contained in the const?

how can I do to continue in the site only if the input value matches one of those in the const?

this is the JS code:

```
enter code here

console.log('ciao benvenuto nella console');

var nomeUtente = window.prompt ("Inserisci il tuo User");

const nomi = [Lorenzo, Angelo, David]

console.log(nomi.includes(nomeUtente))




if (nomeUtente == nomi){
alert('Bentornato ' + nomeUtente +  ' fai click su ok per entrare nel sito');
}

else {
alert('Nome utente errato')
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save your user names as strings in the array. Then check if the array includes the user input.

```js
console.log('ciao benvenuto nella console');

var nomeUtente = window.prompt ("Inserisci il tuo User");

const nomi = ['Lorenzo', 'Angelo', 'David']

if (nomi.includes(nomeUtente)){
  alert('Bentornato ' + nomeUtente +  ' fai click su ok per entrare nel sito');
  console.log(false);
}

else {
  alert('Nome utente errato')
  console.log(true);
}
```

Comment: thank you!! but I still have the problem of not logging into the site if the name is wrong. A re-routing is also fine

Comment: @Lorenzo You can simply log them if you want, I edited the answer. But I'm not sure what is re-routing that you are talking about.

Comment: I'm talking about a way not to let a user who misses the name continue on the site, for example, he is sent to a page with an error message

Comment: @Lorenzo You can use [`window.open`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) for that.

Comment: thak you this is perfect